# Unable to Install Db2 Developer Community Edition - Windows 7 Pro - got stuck at 88%

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I also would like to install  IBM Db2 Developer Community Edition on Windows 7, but  got stuck at 88% showing "Starting services ..."

I attached the log - bottom lines. Could you take a look and advice me?

```
....
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0627] [info] PULL_STATUS = 3876.3856801986694 totalPullStatus = 3876.3856801986694 totalPullSize = 3876.3856801986694  Math.round(totalPullStatus / totalPullSize) = 100
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0631] [info] containerName: data_server_manager_dev progIndex[containerName]: 0 progressStrings[containerName][progIndex[containerName]]: "{ 'Starting server dsweb.': '20' }"
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0631] [info] SearchString = Starting server dsweb.
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0631] [info] containerName: db2_developer_c progIndex[containerName]: 5 progressStrings[containerName][progIndex[containerName]]: "{ '(*) Setup has completed.': '100' }"
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0632] [info] SearchString = (*) Setup has completed.
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0634] [info] containerName: data_studio progIndex[containerName]: 4 progressStrings[containerName][progIndex[containerName]]: "{ '------------------ EXECUTE COMMAND ------------------': '100' }"
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0634] [info] SearchString = ------------------ EXECUTE COMMAND ------------------
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0635] [info] pullProgress = 100 dockerRunProgress =  66.66666666666667
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0636] [info]  size downloaded = 103 total = 103
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0637] [info] docker donwload progress = 96 progress = 87.55555555555556
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0784] [info] Progress from handleStream is: 100
[2018-04-12 18:48:38:0931] [info] Progress from handleStream is: 100
```

Comment: Try again. Ensure you have sufficient RAM and CPU.  I had to retry several times before it succeeded. It's rather poor at the installation job due to the large downloads and does not appear to be able to resume from the point of any failure.

Comment: Also : read this thread https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/439988/unable-to-install-db2-developer-community-edition/ , it has suggestions for manually installing specific components on Win7 *before* installing the Db2-developer edition.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Docker Toolbox component manually is not the solution here as it is already properly installed. 
From the log excerpt it looks like it has downloaded everything and is starting up the services. 
How long did you wait at 88%? Doesn't look like it is stuck unless you gave it too little memory allocation and it is starving and it is starting up super slow. 
If you have already cancelled out of this - give it another try. You can toggle the memory and disk size for Virtual Box if you click "Advanced Settings" on the initial screen.

Comment: Hi Irina, thank you for your support. I wait at 88% over night..  The screen shows for an instant "Internet connection needed" - but surely connecting to the internet. the message says "You an need Internet connection to install IBM Db2 Developer Community Edidion. Connect to the Internet to continue. If the problem persists,check that firewll rules are not blocking any of the following sites: ipinfo.ko, speedtest.net, store.docker.com"

Comment: Hi @mayumihi sorry for the delay. I just got notified of your response. Did you check if your firewall is blocking these sites - ipinfo.io, speedtest.net, store.docker.com ? Usually that internet message will show up when the app can't connect to these sites.